# Pass javascript array to bash script through node child process

Tags: javascript, arrays, bash, child-process

I would like to pass a Javascript array to my bash script to loop over it.

What I am doing now is to call a child Process through node:

```
child = exec(directory + '\\downloadProducts.sh ' + promObj.requestURLS + ' ' + promObj.Name);
```

where `promObj.requestURLS` and `promObj.Name` are arrays.

My bash script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo "params:"
echo "ID: $1"
echo "Name: $2"

declare -a IDArray=$1[@]
declare -a NameArray=$2[@]
echo "${NameArray[0]}"


for id in "${IDArray[@]}"; do
    for name in "${IDArray[@]}"; do
echo "I am " $id $name
  curl -u user:pass 
  "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('"$id"')/\$value" --
   output $DIR/test/$name.zip
echo "download Product" $name
   done
done
echo "FINISHED ALL"
```

How can I pass the arrays properly? Thanks in advance

Comment: To store the output of a command in bash, don't use declare, rather use `my_array="($(my_command))"`

Comment: Did you mean `IDArray="($($1))"`? If so, then the "array" is empty.

Comment: Why not use bash and not node for this?

Comment: The files which I download are about 1GB and I would like to "outsource" this from node.